# Check Service IIS down on nginx load balancing using NGINX

Tags: nginx, high-availability

I setup load balancing with nginx.
Here is my config

```
upstream mywebsite1  {
  least_conn;;
  server xxx.xxx.xxx.20 weight=1 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=15s;
  server xxx.xxx.xxx.21 weight=1 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=15s;
}
```

Default all request sent to 2 sever backend. Now if IIS Service in Backend1 (xxx.xxx.xxx.20) down, Access to website will be interrupted. So how can make all request auto connect to backend2 when IIS service on backend1 down, or connect to backend1 when IIS service on backend2 down ???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `max_fails=3` for each server, so try to seventh requests to the nginx load balancer while server .20 is being down.

You can refer this : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html

Comment: So, In case, how do i have to config nginx ?

Comment: Should set `max_fail=1` , you just have 1 corrput request, then all requests are redirected to live `server`.

Comment: Yep, I working when server down. But if server is online and IIS Pool stop, it not working :(

Comment: Should create a new topic about `IIS down` :)

Comment: Thank for suggest and support. I changed  my question.